# infix prefix postfix

Tags: math

I came across this in some brain teaser question bank.

```
What should be the answer of this?
( (3+1) / 3) * 6

I thought it is 7 but the correct answer is 8.
```

That can happen only when it is (3+1) * (6/3). Since there are parenthesis given in the expression how can I get 8? I tried to double check and the answer is correct.

Can somebody help me in understanding this?

Comment: What brain teaser question bank is this from? It's basic order of operations. When you came up with 7, were you assuming integer division (dropping the remainder)? That's the only reason to come to that answer, that I can think of.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Even if you drop the remainder, you would get 6.

Comment: "brain teaser"?  Oh, my.

Comment: Please do tell how you got 7.

Comment: @sftrabbit Ah, right you are.

Comment: I am sure our friends on http://mathoverflow.net/ would welcome this question ;)

Comment: This question is a very good illustration of the futility of looking at expressions without knowing the data types and their arithmetic operations. If the values were e.g. Java int, then the answer would be 6. If they are rational or real numbers, the answer is 8. I am curious about what they would have to be to get 7.

Answer (score 5):

Working with integers:

```
  ((3 + 1) / 3) * 6 
= (4 / 3) * 6 
= 1 * 6 
= 6
```

Working with floats:

```
  ((3 + 1) / 3) * 6 
= (4 / 3) * 6
= (4 / 3) * (6 / 1)
```

As a [fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29):

```
= (6 * 4) / (3 * 1) 
= 24 / 3 
= 8
```

Comment: +1 for integer division

Comment: @Kirilenko : Isn't numbers like `3` , `1` and `6` are integers. And Can you please explain ***How*** did the precedence of multiplication came over parentheses ?

Comment: @cipher: I assume "integers" as C language defines it. That's how the question was tagged when I've written my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is just simple arithmetic - nothing to do with programming, nor the difference between infix, prefix and postfix notations:

```
((3+1) / 3) * 6 = (4 / 3) * 6
                = 1.333... * 6
                = 8
```

This brain teaser question bank is clearly expecting you to use the usual rules of mathematics - it's not a C brain teaser question bank after all. Even if you were using integer division instead (where `4 / 3` would give `1`), the answer would be 6.

See [the result on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+%283%2B1%29+%2F+3%29+%2a+6).

Answer (score 1):

By the sound of it, this is basic arithmetic and has nothing whatsoever to do with programming:

```
(3 + 1) / 3 * 6 = 
4 / 3 * 6 =
(4 * 6) / 3 =
24 / 3 =
8
```

Comment: You are ignoring a pair of parentheses and altering the order of operations as specified in the original equation. Granted that this *doesn't* have an effect on the final result in *this* case, but you should avoid doing that - or at least be explicit about it.